# AngularJS limitTo by last 2 records

Tags: underscore.js, angularjs

Can a combination of AngularJS [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), [`order`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), or [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) for [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) mimic the [`_.last`](http://underscorejs.org/#last) in UnderscoreJS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly I think [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu7rZ/) would do it.

For this data:

```
$scope.items = [{sort: 1, name: 'First'}, 
                {sort: 2, name: 'Second'}, 
                {sort: 3, name: 'Third'}, 
                {sort: 4, name:'Last'}];
```

If you don't want to actually sort the array and just take the last two items of the array as is (like underscore's last) you can try a negative limit (this would show Third, Last):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:-2">
```

Also note you can chain the filters together like this example sorting the data in reverse and taking 2 items (this would show Last, Third):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'sort':true | limitTo:2">
```

Answer (score 15):

Gloopy's answer is correct, but just a note... If you want to use Underscore, you can:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope._ = _;
});

<div ng-repeat="item in _.last(items)">
```