# Correct paradigm for mixing angular code with external code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular Newbie here.  I'm trying to understand the paradigm to use when developing an Angular app so I can use external libraries while keeping the Angular app reusable.

So imagine I've got a `form` that uses ng-submit:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">...<!--code goes here --></form>
```

And then inside the corresponding `ng-app` and `ng-controller` (assume those are declared in a parent element), I've got my `submit` function.  But say, on this page only, I want to use a custom alert library after submitting:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
// code goes here to submit form data
//now tell the user that save was successful
customAlertLibrary.alert("your data has been saved")
}
```

Now that's not reusable code, is it?  I may want to reuse this `ng-app` on another page to modify and submit data, but don't want to use the custom alert library.  It seems like you're trapped because the `ng-submit` attribute restricts you to functions inside the corresponding `ng-app`, not external functions.  So what is the correct way to invoke other Javascript code alongside my Angular code without baking it into the model?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to [this question about making `lodash` available in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862119/how-to-make-lodash-work-with-angular-js). There are many ways of adding external (or in-app) code or data-structures to your Angular scope. I prefer to add special-purpose stuff to each scope individually, and [general-purpose utilities (such as lodash or momentjs) globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25086064/2228771):

```
app
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope._ = _;
    $rootScope.moment= moment;

    // or:
    // $rootScope.util = {
    //      _: _,
    //      moment: moment
    // };
});
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'm new to Angular.  How do I go about adding things (I want to add a method) to the scope locally, just for a particular page without modifying the global, reusable template?  The example you provide here from `lodash` is for adding to the global scope, correct?

Comment: Yes, this one is global. I'm sure, you are already aware of how to assign stuff to your scope. Like: `$scope._ = _;`...

Comment: I am, but I only know how to access that `$scope` variable inside `app.controller("myController", function($scope){... $scope.attribute = ...}`.  Isn't that the global script that will be imported everywhere this Angular model is used?  Maybe I'm not totally familiar with the Angular paradigm yet.

Comment: @J-bob I'm not following?

Comment: Isn't the idea of Angular that you can declare this model in an external js file and then import and use it on any page?  If I do `$scope.myCustomFunction = some-function-thats-only-used-on-this-page` aren't I cluttering the global scope with functions only used in one place?

Comment: Generally speaking, `$scope` is local. It's contents won't be seen anywhere but inside of your controller's or directive's scope. I'd recommend [brushing up on Angular basics](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-scopes.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69466/discussion-between-j-bob-and-domi).

Answer (score 0):

If customAlertLibrary isn't crucial to your app, I'd say do something like this

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  // code goes here to submit form data
  //now tell the user that save was successful
  if ($window.customAlertLibrary) {
    customAlertLibrary.alert("your data has been saved");
  }
}
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest using Bower to manage dependencies. You install packages with Bower, and your own app can be a package that gets included and installed by other apps. Any dependency your app has gets installed as well (the user still has to include it on their own end in a `<script>` tag)