# provider not found for underscore

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-provider

i have an angularjs factory to which i am injecting underscore and application is working fine but when i try to write jasmine test cases on it i am getting an error underscore provider is not found
i have my factory like

```
angular.module("sample")
.factory("example", example);
 example.$inject = ["$document", "$compile", "$rootScope", "$timeout", "$q", "underscore"];
function example($document, $compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $q, _) {

}
```

and i have my module defined as

```
(function(){
angular.module(samlple,[]);
})();
```

and my test case is as

```
beforeEach(module('sample'));
beforeEach(module('ionic'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($document, $compile, $rootScope, $timeout,underscore,example) {

}
```

its giving error 
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: underscoreProvider <- underscore

Comment: Where is your underscore service defined? I assume it is not in a separate module, since you have no dependencies listed...

Comment: Also, your service names should be surrounded by underscores (ex: _underscore_, _example_) when injecting them using the inject() function in your test.

Answer (score 1):

Add import underscore in your index.html, then add it as a service.

```
var underscore = angular.module('underscore', []);
    underscore.factory('_', function() {
        return window._; // assumes underscore has already been loaded on the page
    });
```

And

```
//Now we can inject underscoreJS in the controllers
function MainCtrl($scope, _) {
  //using underscoreJS method
  _.max([1,2,3,4]); //It will return 4, which is the maximum value in the array
}
```

But I recommend you to use lodash! It has more cool functions. Information about how to use lodash with Angular you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862119/how-to-make-lodash-work-with-angular-js) .

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on @Bakhtier's answer, I used the following to get Karma/Jasmine to recognize lodash so I could use it in my services, as well as the rest of my app.

```
angular.module('app', ['app.services', 'lodash']);
angular.module('app.services', ['lodash']).factory('MyService', ['_', function (_){
    // your code bits
}]);
angular.module('lodash', []).factory('_', function() {
    return window._;
});
```

Hope that helps someone out.