# How to Sum a Json Array value in AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to sum the product count which are added dynamically using JSON array.

```
               <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in form.products">
                    <td>{{ProductName(key)}}</td>
                    <td >
                        <input type="text" name="products" ng-model="form.products[key]" class="form-control">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

How can I get the sum of products in the above example?

Comment: get the count in the controller and make it available in $scope for the template to use in the ng-repeate

Comment: I tried this  $scope.calculateSum = function ()
  {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++)
    {
  
   sum +=  parseFloat($scope.products[i]);
  
      
    }
    return sum;
  } but not working , I called in the template like <input type="text" name="TotalProducts" value="{{calculateSum()}}"  class="form-control" >. I am new to angular JS

Answer (score 0):

use [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

presuming the value you want to sum is in a property called 'price':

```
{{_(form.products).mapValues('price').sum()}}
```

you may need to get lodash into your scope first.  In the controller, something like:

```
scope._ = _;
```

or [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25086064/559378)

Comment: Is it not possible without using lodash? I don't have any property value my array looks like   {"1":20,"2":15,"3":5}, product code and product price

Answer (score 0):

you are using an '*object with properties*' instead of '*an array of objects*', that is why you cant use your example above , ***$scope.products.length;...***.

**Your product object with its properties** :

```
$scope.products ={
"1":"20",//property 1 with value 20
"2":"35",//property 2 with value 35
"3":"150"//property 3 with value 150
}
```

**The data Object (object with properties as you have it)**:

```
 $scope.myData = {"1":120,"2":250,"3":500};
```

**Function that iterates into object's properties and sum the price**:

```
//read object properties and sum price
    $scope.calculateSum = function(data){
    var sum=0;  
    var counter=0;
     for (var property in data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          sum += data[property];
          counter++;
       }
     }
     return sum;
    };
```

**Function that iterates into object properties and count the products**

```
//read object properties and count the products
   $scope.countProducts = function(data){
    var counter=0;
     for (var property in data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          counter++;
       }
     }
     return counter;
    };
```

**Into your HTML template:**

```
  <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in myData track by $index">
   <td>
        <input type="text" name="id" ng-model="key" class="form-control">
  </td>
   <td>      
      <input type="text" name="price" ng-model="value" class="form-control">            
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Products: {{countProducts(myData)}}</td>
    <td>Sum: {{calculateSum(myData)}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

I have done a live example that counts the products and also sum the products price: http://plnkr.co/edit/FmJhvV?p=preview

Hope helps, good luck.