# How to use lodash/underscore in angular config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash, angularjs-config

I'm trying to use underscore or lodash in `angular.module("",[]).config(function(){/* Here */})`, but it is expecting a Provider and throwing `Unknown provider`.

- Should I just use `_` from global scope? (which is not preferrable)
- Is there a way to inject utility like `underscore/lodash` in module config?

Comment: I deleted my answer as there didn't appear to be a provider which could be injected in to the `.config()` call. Only a service was available for use in controllers. The module appears to be quite old anyway.

Comment: Use `app.constant("_", window._);` Constants are injectable during both the config phase and the run phase. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Loading Modules and Dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies) and  [AngularJS Service Components Reference - Constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant).

Answer (score -1):

After further investigation the module I linked wasn't suitable for your requirement. However, I did manage to dig up an older SO question which has some information about defining lodash in an Angular constant, this can be injected in to the `.config()` call.

Here is the question: [How to make lodash work with Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862119/how-to-make-lodash-work-with-angular-js)

I hope this is more useful.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, please add an example of how to use the module inside your answer.

Comment: Quoting the [installing](https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash#installing) section of the doc should be enough.

Comment: So how would I use this in `.config()`?

Comment: I've updated my answer after I found some more information and an old SO question.

Comment: When referring to other answers, you should quote the relevant part so your answer stays relevant, or just comment on the question with a link. If it looks like a duplicate, flag it.