# how to get data in response which getting from server(nodejs expressjs) to angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, httpresponse

```
$http
   .get('/getFollowings/' + currentUser)
   .success(function(response) {
        $scope.friendlist = response;
   });
```

I want to get the data which in response.but i cannot handle those values individually.
'response' contain :

```
[{"_id":"597c9fabc1ada32277f1da34","following":[{"username":"him"},{"username":"ron"},{"username":"nadu"}]}]
```

I want to get this `usernames`.

Comment: Can you explain more detail "individually" word ?

Comment: @Vivz i tried.but couldn't.

Comment: @thelonglqd individually means i want to get just {"him", "ron", "nadu"}

Comment: @IranthiPrarthana Which version of angular are you using and are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `angular.forEach`

```
$scope.usernames = [];
$http.get('/getFollowings/' + currentUser)
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.friendlist = response;
      angular.forEach($scope.friendlist[0].following, function(val) {
          $scope.usernames.push(val.username)
      });
    });
```

Here `$scope.usernames` is an array with all the values of usernames

You can use `ng-repeat` to display these values in  the view.

```js
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     var response = [{
         "_id": "597c9fabc1ada32277f1da34",
         "following": [{
             "username": "him"
         }, {
             "username": "ron"
         }, {
             "username": "nadu"
         }]
     }];
     $scope.usernames = [];
     angular.forEach(response[0].following, function(val) {
         $scope.usernames.push(val.username)
     });
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="username in usernames"><span>{{username}}</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Error: response is not defined'
i got this :(

Comment: You should do this inside success of your API call. Are you sure that your response is of the same structure as mentioned in the question??

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use lodash library , try this :

```
$scope.friendlist = _.chain(response.plain())
                     .map(function(item){
                        item.following = _.pluck(item.following,'username')
                        return item;
                     })
                     .pluck('following')
                     .flatten()
                     .value();
```

Comment: here wht i got :
"Error: _ is not defined"

Comment: Yes, if you have not installed lodash in your project , it is usual. Before  you try , please install.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862119/how-to-make-lodash-work-with-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $http you need to serve Object to client.

Structure:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "597c9fabc1ada32277f1da34",
      "following": [
        {
          "username": "him"
        },
        {
          "username": "ron"
        },
        {
          "username": "nadu"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.friendlist = response.data;
//i think it's simple
for(var i=0;i<$scope.friendlist.length;i++){
    console.log($scope.friendlist[i]);
}
```

Comment: then how do i get each value in '$scope.friendlist' ?

Comment: @IranthiPrarthana You can use "for" or "angular.forEach".

Answer (score 0):

Just use forEach loop to get all username from the array.

```
    $scope.usernameList = [];
    $http
    .get('/getFollowings/' + currentUser)
    .success(function(response) {
       $scope.friendlist = response;           
       $scope.friendlist[0].following.forEach(function(item){
       $scope.usernameList.push(item.username);  
       });
   });
```

So now `$scope.usernameList` contains all the usernames which are in the array named following.