# PapaParse with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, papaparse

Liked the nice CSV parser & unparser of PapaParse. Can any one help me to get this combine with Angular JS.

I like to make PapaParse work in Angular Way. Trying for a solution.

Comment: could you clarify more on PapaParse. usually you could convert any third-party lib into angular service to have easy injection into angular context.

Comment: Is it good to have lib call in controller or need to have a directive for importing file. I'm confused on many other things too

Comment: i would prefer to directly use it in controller, directive is mostly used when you want a DOM created

Comment: https://github.com/stevemao/angular-PapaParse

Comment: https://github.com/Alberthaff/ngx-papaparse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `value` to provide self contained third party libraries.

```
angular.module('your.app')
    .value('yourLib', yourLib);
```

Then in your controller, or service,  you would bring it in the normal way using DI

```
angular.module('your.app')
    .controller('YourController', YourController);

YourController.$inject = ['yourLib'];
function YourController(yourLib) {

   //. . .  
}
```

If the third party line is a constructor function,  requires it be newed, you may want to create a factory or a provider that has a method that accepts the passes params to the constructor returns a new instance.

*Edit*

After looking at PapaParse, you would want to register it with the angular injector using `value`.

Comment: agree with you. Will be helpfull with a example (a fiddle)

Comment: @felix, unfortunately Papaparse isn't hosted anywhere with the correct MIME type -- Stackoverflow, Plunkr and Jsfiddle require the libs have the correct MIME.

Comment: noprops, I got a similar example with another library in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968297/use-underscore-inside-angular-controllers

Comment: @Felix, yes this approach is the same. The only difference is he is using a factory rather than a value. Value is a lighter approach, but both do the same thing.

Comment: it's now hosted on  the following cdn: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.js

Answer (score 7):

I actually didn't do anything fancy to load it. Just add it to html file and to my lib folder. In my case: /lib/papaparse.min.js

and to index.html. As usual script:

```
<script src="lib/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```

then I just used it in my Controller:

```
Papa.parse(data, {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished:", results.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: This approach works fine unless you need to stub or mock PapaParse out for unit testing of your controller. You don't want to get into a situation where you are monkey patching in your test setup.

Answer (score 0):

just use a front-end modularization tool like `requirejs` to load papaParser in the context and call the api in any of your controller or service.

Comment: I had completed my application, just for csv import, i had already need PapaParse so i don't like a new tool to be added. anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Just **inject the script** url in your `index.html` & then in your controller, **access it** as - `var Papa = window.Papa;`. That's it! You are ready for further actions!