# Injecting Underscore.js into Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, angular-controller

I tried two of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968297/use-underscore-inside-angular-controllers) to no avail.

This is my Error:

`angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module flavorApplication due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: underscore`

Here is my code for the module:

```js
var underscore = angular.module('underscore', []);
underscore.factory('_', ['$window', function() {
  return $window._;
}]);
```

Here is my App Config:

```js
(function(){
  angular.module("flavorApplication",
    ['ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.router',
        'angular-loading-bar',
        'angular-confirm',
        ]);
        angular.module("flavorApplication").config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', 
        'underscore', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, underscore){
```

Here I'm trying to inject it into a Controller (probably where I'm going wrong)

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('flavorApplication')
        .controller('UsedSearchesController', UsedSearchesController);

    UsedSearchesController.$inject = ['$stateParams', '$state', 'DataService', '_'];
    function UsedSearchesController($stateParams, $state, DataService, _) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.currentSearches = $stateParams.search.split("|")


        activate(vm);

        ////////////////

        function activate(vm, _) {
            vm.removeSearch = function (searchTerm) {
              $stateParams.search =  _.filter(vm.currentSearches, 
              function(search){return search !== searchterm}).join("|")
                $state.go('home');
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `$window` dependency to inject in your factory

```
underscore.factory('_', ['$window', function($window) {
```

Other thing you can't get `factory/service` singleton object to be avail at config phase of angular, you can't get that object there.

```
//remove 'underscore' dependency from config phase like below.
angular.module("flavorApplication").config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
   function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
```

Additionally, you don't need to add `_` as a parameter in `activate` function,

```
function activate(vm) { //<-- remove _ from here
```

> Don't forget to inject `underscore` module to `flavorApplication`
>   module  so that would make available `_` object throughout application
>   modules & components.

```
angular.module("flavorApplication",
['ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'angular-confirm',
    'underscore' //<-- added underscore module here
]);
```

Comment: But most importantly, he forgot to add `underscore` module as dependency to `flavorApplication` module.

Comment: @dsfq thanks for headsup brother, adding that point to answer

Comment: @dfsq  It's a dependancy there.  Pankaj adding $window didn't fix it

Comment: ah gotcha. I added that and still have the same error thanks @dfsq

Comment: @chrissavage you have to remove `underscore` from config function as I shown in my answer

Comment: That was it... You might want to update your answer. There is no reference to .config, just to the activate function. Thank you!