# Angular JS : How to create a Array dynamically by reading a JSON Array

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON as below

```
[
        {
                "id": 1000,
                "name": "Open"
        },
        {
                "id": 1000,
                "name": "Ravi"
        },
        {
                "id": 1000,
                "name": "POOO"
        }]

    On click of a button I am trying to create a Array by reading all the names from the Array 

    I have tried as follwoing 

        var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope)
{
        $scope.formData = function()
        {
                var aa = $scope.tickets.length;
                $scope.products = $scope.tickets.name;
                alert($scope.products);
        };
        $scope.tickets = [
        {
                "id": 1000,
                "name": "Open"
        },
        {
                "id": 1000,
                "name": "Ravi"
        },
        {
                "id": 1000,
                "name": "POOO"
        }]
});
```

Currently i am getting undefined , could you please let me know how to do this
Thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/434/

**I dont want tradional style using  a for loop to read .**

Could you please suggest a professional approach .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a loop to read all data in array and push them to your new array:

```
$scope.formData = function()
{
    $scope.products = [];
    var aa = $scope.tickets.length;
    angular.forEach($scope.tickets, function(value, key) {
        $scope.products.push(value.name);
    });
    alert($scope.products);
};
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/435/)

Answer (score 1):

If you won't to use a loop to read, then you can use `Underscore.js`.

By using `Underscore.js` you can do this as below. before that you need to check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968297/use-underscore-inside-angular-controllers) for how use underscore inside angular controllers.

```
var result = _.map([{ id: 1, name: "vinit"},{ id: 2, name: "jaimin"}], function (v) {
    return v.name;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

[jsfilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp67hp3m/2/)